# How to stop crawling the admin with strapi and nuxt

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, admin, strapi, robots.txt

I have a project created with strapi and nuxt. When i try to block the link admin.mywebsite.com from being crawled in the live version with the robots.txt, it doesn't work. I tried to disallow the /admin, but that didn't work. It would be possible to block the strapi admin page on the live website? thank you for your help

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin
```

Comment: /admin is not the same as admin.mysite.com

Comment: is there a way to block this type of admin in robot.txt? I'm sorry, I didn't find nothing online and I'm not an expert on robots.txt